# Why are scss modules in a different component overriding some of the css in my current component in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm working on styling my react app with imported scss modules (using node-sass). I would like to create a .scss file for each component. I finished styling my landing page and everything was fine, but when I moved on to my login page the CSS Grid layout was being overridden by the landing page's scss file since I was grabbing the 'root' div in each scss file and creating the grid layout in there. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out after taking a little break. I'm being very specific in my class names for each component just to make sure nothing conflicts and i'm using toggle/remove of unique class names for each component for my root div in the lifecycle methods of each component.